Vimeo API shows "NULL" for number of plays even though vimeo.com publicly displays the number of plays. Is there something I'm missing?
The Vimeo API reference describes how to get video information, and using the "try it" api tester I'm able to see the number of plays on a video, which matches the number i see when looking at the same video on vimeo.com
For example, https://vimeo.com/892335850 shows more than 200 plays, the "try it" API result matches, but the API response from my PHP client is null.
I've tried other endpoints and other channels, and same result across the board.
Is it a problem with my API key? Am i missing some trick with the API?
Any pointers would be great.
